# Target only one navigation with CSS animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations, bootstrap-4

I have a navigation bar, that has another navigation inside it. And I want to add an effect to it similar to what these guys have [here](https://comotion.studio/). But my problem is that second nav. Because I only want animations to apply to the first, main nav. Not the second one too. How can I achieve that?

Here's my code so far:

```css
.second-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 8px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

/* Navbar opacity on hover */
.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav:hover > .nav-item:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="nav second-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Plus, instead of scaling the hovered item, my code makes the rest of the links bigger. How can I fix that as well? Thank you?